# Grails local ehcache configured in combination with remote Terracotta

Tags: grails, configuration, ehcache, terracotta

We have ehcache configured in our Grails environment and I'm trying to ascertain how a local cache can be configured with a remote terracotta cache.

The scenario is that we have some data that is minimally expensive to calculate and benefits from a local in-memory cache but the benefit is minimized when using the remote terracotta cache.

The config is currently pretty simple:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" >
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
  <cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties=""/>
  <defaultCache
       maxElementsInMemory="20000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToLiveSeconds="12000"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       diskPersistent="false">
    <terracotta />
  </defaultCache>
  <terracottaConfig url="${com.ngs.app.tc.host}:${com.ngs.app.tc.port}" />

  <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
      maxElementsInMemory="10000"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"/>

  <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
      maxElementsInMemory="10000"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"/>
</ehcache>
```

The questions are:

1. Given the config above, does this imply that a cache put / get will always do a round trip to the terracotta server?
2. Is there a possible configuration where it will use a local "hot" cache before doing the round trip to the server?
3. If a local "hot" cache is to be used, this would need to be implemented programmatically using a different cache configuration, not backed by terracotta?

Thanks for any advice ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- The configuration above only declares the default cache to be clustered, the named caches are not clustered.
- Ehcache works with a tiering system, so that means that even for a clustered cache, the setting of `maxElementsInMemory` will apply to a on-heap tier of the cache, local to each JVM part of the Terracotta cluster. Note: `maxElementsInMemory` is deprecated and should be replaced by `maxEntriesLocalHeap` in recent Ehcache versions.

Given this, here are the basic operations and their relation to the clustered bit of the cache:

- Get with a local hit: only touches the on-heap tier, no Terracotta round trip
- Get with a local miss: will go try to find the value in the cluster - Terracotta round trip
- Put: will need to update the cluster - *Terracotta round trip*
- Remove: will need to update the cluster - *Terracotta round trip*

For these last two operations, the default configuration decouples the local operation from the clustered one. If you cannot handle reading stale value, you can play with the [consistency setting](http://terracotta.org/generated/4.2.0/html/bmm-all/#page/BigMemory_Max_Documentation_Set%2Fco-cfgdist_consistency_modes.html).

This means that answers to your questions are:

1. See above
2. Yes
3. Yes and no: if you need only the local part, you can have a local only cache, just omit the `terracotta` element in the cache configuration. If you need the clustered bit but want most cache hits to be local hits, you need to tweak your clustered cache configuration.

Comment: this was a great answer thank you. It's seems difficult to get a good source of Terracotta / ehcache documentation.